# how to dynamically create hashmap key in java?

Tags: java, android, hash

I need to implement and expandable list view where it extracts values from database and updates the Gui.so i need to store the values retrieved from cursor in hash map so i need dynamically add hash keys to hash-map and values.
code :

```
for(int i=0;i<=1;i++){
         List resTimeArraySms=new ArrayList();
        resultCursorSMS = NTDBHelper.getInstance().getResultDataByMediaType(getApplicationContext(), "Plan1",1);

        while (resultCursorSMS.moveToNext()){

            HashMap resHash=new HashMap();
            resTimeStampSms = resultCursorSMS.getLong(resultCursorSMS.getColumnIndex(NTDataProvider.KEY_RESULTS_TIME_STAMP));
            resHash.put("timestampsms", resTimeStampSms);
            resTimeArraySms.add(resHash);

        } 



     resTimeArray.add(resTimeArraySms);
    }
```

Comment: It's not very clear what you are asking for. Have you tried coding this? Could you show some code (even pseudo-code) of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I believe you should elaborate on your question
In general the point in hash-like structure is that you get the value-by the key very fast O(1)
value = get(key)
Now, do you asking how to generate random Strings to be used as keys of your hash?

Comment: Please Edit your question ..what are u trying to ask??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to create a counter and use the counter as the key and increment the counter value after each insertion

**Example**

```
int counter = 0;
            for(int i=0;i<=1;i++){
                List resTimeArraySms=new ArrayList();
               resultCursorSMS = NTDBHelper.getInstance().getResultDataByMediaType(getApplicationContext(), "Plan1",1);

               while (resultCursorSMS.moveToNext()){

                   HashMap resHash=new HashMap();
                   resTimeStampSms = resultCursorSMS.getLong(resultCursorSMS.getColumnIndex(NTDataProvider.KEY_RESULTS_TIME_STAMP));
                   resHash.put("timestampsms"+counter, resTimeStampSms);
                   resTimeArraySms.add(resHash);
                   counter++;
               } 



            resTimeArray.add(resTimeArraySms);
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to generate hashcode for the object retrieved from the DB, have a look at the HashCodeBuilder from commons-lang.